# How to retrieve JSON from HTTP Post request inside Google Endpoint method?

Tags: java, android, json, post, endpoint

I have followed the setup to get Push Notifications from Gmail API to my application as given here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

I have configured a Google Endpoint method shown below to receive the HTTP POST callback (Webhook Push) from Gmail. This is working and getting called on new email.

```
@ApiMethod(
            name = "myhandler",
            path = "_ah/push-handlers/myhandler",
            httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST
    )
    public void myhandler(NotificationMessage notificationMessage) throws IOException {

        //process message

    }
```

Now, the callback from Gmail sends the below JSON structure in the HTTP POST body of the request:

```
POST https://yourserver.example.com/yourUrl
Content-type: application/json

{
  message:
  {
    // This is the actual notification data, as base64url-encoded JSON.
    data: "eyJlbWFpbEFkZHJlc3MiOiAidXNlckBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsICJoaXN0b3J5SWQiOiAiMTIzNDU2Nzg5MCJ9",

    // This is a Cloud Pub/Sub message id, unrelated to Gmail messages.
    message_id: "1234567890",
  }

  subscription: "projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysubscription"
}
```

I am trying to retrieve this data using the NotificationMessage object that I have defined like this:

```
public class NotificationMessage {
    JSONObject message;

    public JSONObject getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(JSONObject message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

How should I change this class or change my Endpoint method to also retrieve the one-level deeper message.data JSON value from the above HTTP POST request?

I have checked out similar questions but not found any which shows how can I retrieve values embedded within the JSON of the POST request, specifically in a Google Java Endpoint method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update on this:

Meanwhile, with the help of http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ , I was able to get the Java classes corresponding to the JSON data mentioned in the question and I used these in the Endpoint API. It works fine now!